# How to dynamically assigning style properties to element?

Tags: javascript

```
function styling(elem, props) {
            for (var i in props) {
                if (i == "color") {
                    elem.style.color = props[i].toString();
                }
                if (i == "background") {
                    elem.style.background = props[i].toString();
                }
            }
```

**Using it:**

```
   styling(links, { color: "blue", background: "yellow" });
```

I'm not really happy with the if-clauses and I want to dynamically add the style properties to the element, but I'm not sure how to do it. Someone out there would know how to do it?

**Solved it**

```
  function styling(elem, props) {
        for (var i in props) {
            elem.style[i] = props[i].toString();
        }
    }
```

That seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, it'll solve all of your problems :) http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I want to work with native prototypes and javascript is beautiful as it is.

Comment: I agree with @poo. As much as I like working with jQuery, questions about native Javascript are allowed here. ;P